# Can we access XCMp functions by writing moonbeam smart contract?

Tags: moonbeam

If my contracts which are deployed on moonbeam wants to interact with contracts deployed on acala (or) astar (or) any other parachain under polkadot hub, Is it possible to acheive it?

Comment: As of now I don't think there is any way via `XCM` to interact between contracts on different parachains